# How can I easily make my own custom setup.py commands?

Tags: python, shell, setup.py

In JavaScript projects, I can specify following in my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "dredd",
  "version": "1.0.4",
  "description": "API Blueprint testing tool",
  "main": "lib/dredd.js",
  "bin": {
    "dredd": "bin/dredd"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "coffeelint ./src",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "test": "find ./test/ -name '*-test.coffee' | xargs mocha --compilers 'coffee:coffee-script/register' --reporter spec --timeout 120000 --recursive",
    ...
    "coveralls": "./scripts/coveralls.sh",
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
```

See the `scripts` section. I can define any "script" of any name and any implementation. Then I can run it as `npm run <name>` (and some special ones I can even run directly as `npm <name>`, for instance `npm test`). Implementation of "script" can be just a single command or a line which works the same way as it would work in my shell (while portability is something I need to achieve on my own, `npm` doesn't help me with it, but that's OK). npm correctly propagates any given arguments and also exit codes. So to sum up, I can:

- define custom commands
- define `pre<name>` commands which will be executed always before `<name>` command gets invoked
- these commands can be basically anything what would otherwise run in my terminal
- they correctly propagate arguments and exit code, out of the box
- ideally, the parent command could list available scripts

So it's something like `rake`, `make`, `grunt`, `gulp`, etc., but built-in and very simple, very easy to manipulate. I miss something like this in Python projects. I feel that `setup.py` is a file which was originally meant as a **single entry point** to Python projects and I like the idea and I'd like to embrace it. Ideally, I'd like to have something like:

```
python setup.py test
python setup.py lint
python setup.py <my command>
```

I want single entry point, because I want my project to be intuitive. People should not be forced to read documentation or `.travis.yml` to run linter, tests, etc. for my project. They should not need to care whether I use `nosetests` or `py.test` for testing or `flake8` for linting. That's implementation detail.

However, this is apparently not easy to achieve. E.g. I'd like my `lint` command to internally contain `flake8` and maybe also other stuff. Then I'd like my `test` command to also always run `lint` before it's ran itself.

I've seen some ways to implement custom commands by subclassing `Command` and having a declaration of such command in `setup(...)` in `setup.py`, but I found no nice official documentation. Also, many articles are old and it's very hard to understand current state of things and current best practice in 2016 as there are historically multiple projects dealing with packaging (`distutils`, `setuptools`, `pip`, `easy_install`, ...). Even if I'm able to implement the class and call it and have the command listed on `python setup.py --help`, I'd still have to implement myself the subprocess part, exit code, stdin, stderr and arguments redirection. That's way too complex for my scenario, I want to keep my project simple and focused on it's own purpose.

Test frameworks usually go the way of implementing some heavyweight custom commands which can be set as replacement for the `python setup.py test`. Implementation is on hundreds of lines and if I want to add something to the command (e.g. if I'd like to `flake8 && pytest tests` every time I invoke `python setup.py test`), that seems to be hardly achievable.

I've seen many people to resign on proper design of the commands as they're too difficult to write and they [just do following](http://www.pydanny.com/python-dot-py-tricks.html):

```
# setup.py
if sys.argv[0] == 'test':
    # do something

if sys.argv[0] == 'publish':
    # do something

setup(...
```

That's simple, but it's not integrated to existing `setup.py` infrastructure and I still need to implement all the subprocess work myself if I want to just call a shell command. Also I'm not sure one can easily invoke the original command (e.g. I want to wrap `python setup.py test` with something, so I'll write down the `if sys.argv[0] == 'test':` block and do something custom, but how can I continue with testing afterwards? Again, found no docs for this...).

Neither of options above is easy to write or maintain. However, I don't believe there's nothing like what I'm looking for in Python ecosystem. I think I have to be missing something. Could someone point me at least to the right direction? At least explain me the situation with `setuptools` and `distutils` and where can I find all relevant documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super simple barebones approach. Requires that `flake8` is installed on your system though.

```
class Flake8(Command):
    def initialize_options(self):
        pass

    def finalize_options(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        errno = os.system("flake8 <dir-needing-linting>")
        sys.exit(errno)
```